# Prestashop LOG: get DUMP of Object and Array

Tags: prestashop, symfony-2.8, prestashop-1.7

I am figuring out how Prestashop 1.7 works and I have some experience with Symfony.

In Symfony development mode  `[Symfony project url]/_profiler` is useful, among other things, to check the `dump($someVariable)` of variables in a request.

With Prestashop 1.7 in the **admin mode** it is possible to do `[Prestashop project url]/admin[some random chain of chars]/_profiler` to display the Symfony `_profiler` and analyse what's going on in the requests concerning the admin mode.

But if outside the admin mode (in the **virtual shop demo mode**),   `[Prestashop project url]/_profiler` or `[Prestashop project url]/[language value]/_profiler` **does not display the Symfony `_profiler`**.

I have tried Prestashop own profiler by activating `define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', true);` in `[prestashop project]/config/defines.inc.php`. It displays Prestashop profiler at the bottom of the "virtual shop demo mode" but this one does not include `dump($someVariable)` that could be used, for development and to understand Prestashop behaviour, in a `hookAction[action name]`.

I've managed to get the Symfony `dump($someVariable)` with `hookDisplay[display name]` through the HTML generated **but not in a `hookAction[action name]`** which is what I am looking for.

**UPDATE**
Looking at Prestashop 1.7 code I almost have the feeling that Symfony is only used on the Admin side, because I can see:
`$kernel = new AppKernel(_PS_MODE_DEV_?'dev':'prod', _PS_MODE_DEV_);` in `[Prestashop project url]/admin[some random chain of chars]/index.php` but I don't see it in `[Prestashop project url]/index.php`.

Answer (score 3):

Best solution I've found so far is to create a custom logger similar to the one [explained here](https://www.h-hennes.fr/blog/2016/03/23/prestashop-mise-en-place-de-logs-rapides-dans-un-fichier/)

I've created file: `[Prestashop project]/modules/[my module]/classes/CustomLogger.php`

```
<?php
class CustomLogger {
    const DEFAULT_LOG_FILE ="prestashop_system.log";
    public static function log($message, $level = 'debug', $fileName = null){
        $fileDir = _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/log/';
        $fileName=self::DEFAULT_LOG_FILE;
        if(is_array($message) || is_object($message)){$message = print_r($message, true);}
        $formatted_message=$level." -- ".date('Y/m/d - H:i:s').": ".$message."\r\n";
        return file_put_contents($fileDir . $fileName, $formatted_message, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
?>
```

In '[Prestashop project]/modules/[my module]/[my module].php' it is declared at the top:
`include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/CustomLogger.php';`

And use `CustomLogger::log($[some variable]);` in your code.